# TextArea inside VBox is not scaling vertically

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm creating a simple GUI with JavaFX, but I stumbled upon a problem. Whenever I resize my GUI vertically. My `TextAre` doesn't resize itself, although it should fill the space.

**MainClass**

```java
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        mainWindow(primaryStage);
    }

    private void mainWindow(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainWindow.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            Parent root = loader.load();

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            primaryStage.setMinWidth(270);
            primaryStage.setMinHeight(450);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {}
    }
}
```

**FXML:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.input.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane minHeight="400.0" minWidth="240.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <VBox>
         <children>
            <GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="110.0" prefWidth="240.0">

            </GridPane>
            <VBox>
               <children>
                  <Label text="Results:" />
                  <TextArea fx:id="resultArea" minHeight="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin></VBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

What do I have to add, therewith my TextArea resizes itself vertically?

Comment: Have you tried setting the TextArea max height to `MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: @Sedrick Yes, but it didn't help. My TextArea just doesn't react at all. I also tried to use `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` as well with no success.

Comment: My guess is that your problem is due to `GridPane` being a parent. I am not sure. You need to post working FXML.

Comment: @Sedrick I add the code of my `center`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Break your code down to working code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Sedrick My code is working. It just doesn't resize. That's why I'm asking for help..... if i could brake it down and solve the problem myself I wouldn't need help......

Comment: @Sedrick This is only the fxml file. This file contains all required information. If you want to integrate it into your IDE you'd have to create a project, write your `@override start()` method instantiate a new `FXMLLoader` and so one. -> What you're asking for is my entire project. This is not the intention of SO.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra What do you need? I have searched the web and didn't find anything that was usefull. This is my FXML code. Is this not enough? What kind of information are you seeking? Every other line of code I've written in my project belongs to actions.

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly

Comment: @kleopatra Yes, I've read it and honestly I'm confident that my code, that I've provided, is reproducable.

Comment: actually, it isn't - or which magical IDE are you using, that supports taking that snippet as-is and run it without adding anything? it wont even load without errors

Comment: @kleopatra So, shall I post my project? - I can do that if this helps.

Comment: no, nobody wants to wade through tons of unrelated code .. follow the help page.

Comment: @kleopatra That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I want to provide the necessary code to solve this problem. And I don't want to post unrelated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230614/discussion-between-gentle-sama-and-kleopatra).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that the `VBox` holding your `TextArea` is only going to take up as much space as it needs, so it does not expand when you resize the window.

To fix that, you need to set the VGrow property of your `VBox` to `ALWAYS`, either in Scene Builder:

[image: screenshot]

Or your FXML:

```
<VBox VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
```